# String 999999999.9999999999 is rounded to 1,000,000,000 BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a problem where my 999999999.9999999999 String is being rounded to 1,000,000,000 BigDecimal when I parse it.

Code:

```
NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.0000000000######");
format.setParseIntegerOnly(false);
Number number = format.parse(text);
```

Result:
number = 1.0E9

If I use the same format to parse the result BigDecimal back to String:

```
format.format(number) results in 1,000,000,000
```

Why does this happen and how I can force the original format.parse(text) call not to round?

Comment: What happens if you create a `new BigDecimal("999999999.9999999999")`?

Comment: You might be somehow victim of this line of code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/text/DigitList.java#209 in `java.text.DigitList.getBigDecimal` called by `java.text.DecimalFormat.parse`, but I have no idea why or how.

Comment: @Pimgd, the result of that is 999999999.9999999999. However The above code is part of a bigger validation logic and that's why I need to resolve that rounding issue without having to modify the entire way of how we do things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there's some code you've omitted, `parse` is returning a `Double`, not a `BigDecimal`.  (Try `System.out.println(number.getClass())` to check this.)

If you want a `BigDecimal`, you have to use `setParseBigDecimal` to tell it to return a `BigDecimal`.  (And to do that, `format` has to be declared as `DecimalFormat`.)

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.0000000000######");
format.setParseBigDecimal(true);
Number number = format.parse(text);
```